# ZendFramework 2 - Problems with AbstractFactoryInterface; Param doesn't contain route/controller Namespace

Tags: zend-framework2

I've got a module with one route and an abstract controller factory.

The route

```
namespace BaseApi;

use BaseApi\Factory\Controller\AbstractApiControllerFactory;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [

            'v2a-api' => [
                'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/api/:controller',
                    'defaults' => [
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'BaseApi\Controller',
                    ],
                ],

            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'abstract_factories' => [
            AbstractApiControllerFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

The abstract controller factory

```
namespace BaseApi\Factory\Controller;

use BaseApi\Controller\ApiController;
use BaseApi\Exception\ApiAbstractControllerFactoryException;
use Zend\Filter\Inflector;
use Zend\Filter\StringToLower;
use Zend\Filter\Word\CamelCaseToDash;
use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

/**
 * Class AbstractApiControllerFactory
 *
 * @package BaseApi\Factory\Controller
 */
class AbstractApiControllerFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface
{


    /**
     * @param \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $controllerManager
     * @param $name
     * @param $requestedName
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $controllerManager, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        dump('api', $name, $requestedName);
        $serviceManager = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator();

        $configKey = $this->getConfigKey($requestedName);

        $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');

        return (
            strpos($requestedName, 'BaseApi\Controller') === 0
            && key_exists(
                $configKey,
                !empty($config['d3-api']) ? $config['d3-api'] : []
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $controllerManager
     * @param $name
     * @param $requestedName
     *
     * @return \BaseApi\Controller\ApiController
     * @throws \BaseApi\Exception\ApiAbstractControllerFactoryException
     */
    public function createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $controllerManager, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $serviceManager = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator();

        $configKey = $this->getConfigKey($requestedName);

        $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');

        if (empty($config['d3-api'][$configKey]['service'])) {
            throw ApiAbstractControllerFactoryException::missingServiceKey($configKey);
        }
        if (!$serviceManager->has($config['d3-api'][$configKey]['service'])) {
            throw ApiAbstractControllerFactoryException::missingServiceException(
                $config['d3-api'][$configKey]['service']
            );
        }

        return new ApiController(
            $serviceManager->get($config['d3-api'][$configKey]['service'])
        );
    }

    /**
     * Transforms Controller-Name + Namespace $requestedName in the related Config-Key
     * :: BaseApi\Controller\GameLists => game-lists
     *
     * @param $requestedName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getConfigKey($requestedName)
    {
        $controllerName = substr($requestedName, strrpos($requestedName, '\\') + 1);

        $inflector = new Inflector(':classname');

        $inflector->setFilterRule(
            ':classname',
            [
                CamelCaseToDash::class,
                StringToLower::class,
            ]
        );

        return $inflector->filter(['classname' => $controllerName]);
    }
}
```

Additional config (doesn't matter for this problem, only for completeness sake)

```
<?php

return [
    'd3-api' => [
        'customers' => [
            'service' => 'V2aCustomerDb\Service\Customers',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now my problem: I've got 2 ZF-MVC-Apps. In one, everything works fine; I see my objects when I start a request under `/api/customers`. In the other one, the parameter $requestedName of AbstractApiControllerFactory::canCreateServiceWithName doesn't contain the namespace. I only receive `customers` instead of `BaseApi\Controller\customers`

The project-setup is the same. Everything installed over composer has the same version. So it has to be a config-bug, but after several hours, I've got no clue, what it might be...

someone any suggestions?

Comment: I just aware if there is local config that override your module config. Please check the `config cache` file. Usually it store in `data/cache/module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php`.

This is the merging config, so if the config is not same with your module config, it mean there is another local config which override it.

Comment: Thx for the hint, but I don't have that file (at this moment)

Comment: Hmm, it mean you need to see the *router configuration* from `$serviceManager->get('Config')`. Just to see it was overriden or not

Comment: I've checked the parameter of Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment::__construct and inside the $defaults array there is "__NAMESPACE__" => "BaseApi\Controller"

I checked the config, too and even there, under router => routes => v2a-api => options => defaults there is one element: "__NAMESPACE__" => "BaseApi\Controller" - the config output was inside of AbstractApiControllerFactory::canCreateServiceWithName

Comment: I also attached the 'route' event. With $event->getRouter()->getRoutes() I can see, that the route itself look good. I'm a little bit concerned, because ` #routeMatch: null` doesn't look right; but I can't figure it out, why it's still working within the second project and why the route doesn't match...

Answer (score 0):

After two days...

Module.php has to look like this (add BootstrapListenerInterface)

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2014 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace CustomerDatabase;

use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\BootstrapListenerInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;

/**
 * Class Module
 *
 * @package CustomerDatabase
 */
class Module implements BootstrapListenerInterface
{
    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
    {
        $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: So, this `Module.php` is different with the another one?

Comment: Right. I've used RBAC in the other project and so I already needed the ModuleRouteListener for that. In this moment, I'm not sure, why these three lines are necessary, but it works fine.